# Twitter Link Image Fetch issue

Tags: url, twitter, meta-tags

I have a Wordpress website and I am sharing the link on different websites like Facebook, Instagram.

When I try to share link in Twitter the Link Image does not load.

I have additional settings in wordpress for Social Snippet(which I have set correctly).

I have tried adding twitter meta tags and still not working.

Any help would be useful.